# SQL server RUNNABLE process

Tags: sql-server, blocking

I've a process that is open since 2 days ago and is executing a select as last command, but this session got stuck in `runnable` status.

I checked `inputbuffer` several times and everytime it shows the same query
I will share you the result of `sp_who2` and please note that last batch is for 2 days ago:

[image]

I checked query plan and didn't find any unusual things and it takes 1 second to show result but it's still in my active expensive query in activity monitor

[image]

other point is I ran profiler for this `SPID` since yesterday and here is the result :

[image]

this process lock some objects on my db and it blocks and rebuilding index on this tables

[image]

now what should I do ? should I kill it without finding root cause?

`sp_WhoIsActive` result
[image]
[image]
[image]

the result of `EXEC sp_WhoIsActive @find_block_leaders = 1, @sort_order = '[blocked_session_count] DESC', @get_locks =1` 
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please download sp_whoisactive( http://whoisactive.com/) from Mr. Adam Machanic and share the result as sp_who2 is thread-based and not process based.

Comment: Thanks for you answer , the result is added

Comment: That looks like quite a lot of CPU usage.  Does the CPU usage change when you execute `sp_whoisactive` multiple times?  You might get more information by using the `@get_plans option` for `sp_whoisactive` - [sp_whoisactive: "Planning" for Success](http://whoisactive.com/docs/11_planning/)

Comment: Yes CPU usage is increasing

Comment: sorry , check it again

Comment: Did you check if SPID 84 is blocked by some other process? I can see that 84 is not blocking any other process.

Comment: yes , it's not blocked by other processes, and it doesn't block others except I run rebuild on some tables

Comment: Rebuild was completed? Could you please include the complete result of sp_whoisactive masking your sensitive details(hostname, ProcessName). Please run below command --> EXEC sp_WhoIsActive
    @ find_block_leaders = 1,
    @ sort_order = '[blocked_session_count] DESC',
 @ get_locks =1

Comment: Please remove the space between @ and parameters. I had to put space as DBA.SE is considering that as user's name.

Comment: Check this thread also - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/242406/sql-script-stuck-with-status-runnable-and-wait-preemptive-os-reportevent

Comment: sure , i added new result

Comment: Dynamics AX has a "synchronize database" function that drops all indexes on all tables and creates them again.  Check with your Dynamics AX administrator to see if a database sync was started.  I wouldn't expect it to take 2 days, but if it is getting blocked by other processes for long periods of time or you have I/O issues I could see it taking days.

Comment: @TonyHinkle This is not a synchronize since it's actually selecting inventory transactions. Good suggestion though.

Comment: Can you add the execution plan for this query?

Comment: I can't open www.brentozar.com , do you know other way to share?

Comment: Please use this link to paste the plan --> https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Unfortunately my country is banned from this site, I can’t find any website like that